# Deriving conditional independence statements for causal graphs with selection nodes

Tags: causality, graphical-model, causal-diagram, selection-bias, d-separation

In "basic" causal graphs / DAGs / probabilistic graphical models (PGMs), conditional independence statements can be derived using the d-separation criterion. How does this work if selection nodes (modeling sample selection biases) are present in the graph?

Purely empirically, I see that e.g. [dagitty](https://dagitty.net/) derives different conditional independence statements depending on whether I make the node "S" in the below graph a sample selection node or a standard variable node, but I could not find a description of the underlying theory / conditions.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selection nodes are always conditioned on, because we always implicitly condition on “sampled=true”. It’s impossible to observe the population that was not selected into the sample. Once you realise S is always in the conditioning set the d-separation formula is straightforward to apply and you should get the same results as dagitty.

Comment: Ahh yes of course, that makes sense. Thank you!